# Exporting csv with all quotations in Rstudio

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, quotations

I am trying to export a csv file that I have been working on. To upload it I need to have the separators as ; and quotations around all fields including those as dates. 
I have tried:

```
write.table(original, file = "Original2.csv", append = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = ";", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE)
```

with my file being called original, when I export and view it in notepad++ there are no quotations there. I have tried adding the quotes in excel after and it doesn't work on the dates so that isn't an option either.
 
If I even attempt to do it manually I know I am going to make mistakes so I want to automate it.

Any help is much appreicated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by first converting all your columns to strings, and then saving as a csv. This is fairly straightforward using `dplyr::mutate_all`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
example = data.frame(
    'A' = c(1, 2, 3), 
    'B' = c(as.Date('1970-01-01'), as.Date('1971-01-01'), as.Date('1972-01-01'))
    )

example %<>% mutate_all(as.character)

write.table(example, 'test.csv', sep=';')
```